# Is a sequence $(1/(n-5^-)$ bounded or unbounded? $5^-$ means limit from left.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's have a sequence $(1/(n-5^-)$ where $5^-$ means limit from left.
For $n=5$ the value of the sequence is infinite. Don't we call this unbounded from above, why?

Comment: Why? Because if it's infinite then... it's... not... bounded...

Comment: Doesn`t this sequence have a limit;0? Shouldn`t this be a bounded sequence?

Comment: I think your confusing when $n$ approaches infinity vs $n$ approaches $5^-$

Comment: To my knowledge for the sequence to be bounded there should be a number M which all term of the sequence should be smaller than. In this case when n=5, there is no such M so the sequence should be named unbounded I believe. Then what about the theories that tell all unbounded sequences diverge, as this unbounded sequence has a limit as well?

Comment: What do you think the limit of this unbounded sequence is?

Comment: I was thinking limit of this sequence is 0

Comment: Why do you think the limit of this sequence is 0?